# VS code powershell azure function debugging omnisharp exception

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am having trouble debugging powershell function in vs code.
Vs code: 1.68.0
Azure core tools: v4
Powershell : 7

launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [   
    
    {
      "name": "Attach to PowerShell Functions",
      "type": "PowerShell",
      "request": "attach",
      "customPipeName": "AzureFunctionsPSWorker",
      "runspaceId": 1,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"      
    }    
  ]
}
```

and function code:

run.ps1

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

this error (please see exception link) is occurring as soon as I hit f5. though I can see the host start task is starting but debugging is interrupted with this exception

can someone please help me in this issue?

[image: Exception]

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you; here's how to do it yourself going forward: [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our end, getting the same issue when debugging the Azure Functions PowerShell in VS Code:

[image]

I have tried with different scenarios, but debugging didn't work:

- Tried by changing the C# version in VS Code Extensions
- Restarting the VS Code, steps present in this GitHub Repo of [Omnisharp-VSCode](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-Beta-Releases)

I suggest raising the ticket as a bug in the GitHub Repo of [Omnisharp-vscode](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues) for quick resolution.

Comment: thanks a lot @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT. i will raise a ticket as a bug

Comment: github ticket: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5279

Comment: Thanks @Lavi for sharing the ticket here which would help all of the community members to get update on this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else logged an issue against the vscode-azurefunctions project last week and was able to resolve it:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3184

> 1. Removed the extensionBundle section from host.json file
> 2. Ran this command in the PowerShell terminal: func extensions install –force
> 3. This analyzed my functions and reported that extension C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) needed to be installed.
>
> Once the C# for Visual Studio Code extension was installed, was able to successfully debug my PowerShell Azure Functions.

Comment: Tried same steps but still getting the same error.

Comment: Tried with both c# extension installed and uninstalled. same error

Comment: I'd maybe upvote or comment on the issue I linked as well with your environment information and errors to see if anyone there can assist too. Not sure that omniSharp repo is the right place for it.

Comment: will raise ticket here too. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunction

Comment: ticket raised https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3223